# Single blur event on multiple inputs

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 inputs (firstname, lastname), and want to bind single blur event. How to approach it?

```
class SimpleForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
      firstName: "",
      firstNameError: "",
      lastName: "",
      lastNameError: ""
    };

    validateName = name => {
        const regex = /[A-Za-z]{3,}/;

        return !regex.test(name)
          ? "The name must contain at least three letters. Numbers and special characters are not allowed."
          : "";
      };

    onLastNameBlur = () => {
        const { lastName } = this.state;

        const lastNameError = this.validateName( lastName) ;

        return this.setState({ lastNameError });
      };

    onFirstNameBlur = () => {
        const { firstName } = this.state;

        const firstNameError = this.validateName( firstName );

        return this.setState({ firstNameError });
      };

    onNameChange = e =>
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});

    render() {
    const { firstNameError, firstName, lastName, lastNameError } = this.state;

    return (
      <div style={style.form}>
        <TextField name="firstName"
                   label="First name:"
                   onChange={this.onNameChange}
                   onBlur={this.onFirstNameBlur}
                   error={firstNameError} />

        <TextField name="lastName"
                   label="Last name:"
                   onChange={this.onNameChange}
                   onBlur={this.onLastNameBlur}
                   error={lastNameError} />

        <Greetings firstName={firstName} lastName={lastName} />
      </div>
    );
    }
  }

export default SimpleForm;
```

if u see, we have onLastNameBlur and onFirstNameBlur has similar code. This example I got from https://github.com/suzdalnitski/medium-intro-react

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you onNameChange, you can know the current input with `e.target.name`;

Comment: but how to know current error? we have firstNameError and lastNameError states...

Comment: You can use a switch statement to handle the different cases.